# Section Numbering without Title (`\newtheorem` inquiry)

Tags: amsthm

How can I make use of `\section` (for numbering purposes) without the big section title.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{theorem}
hello
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
hello again 
\end{theorem}
```

In other words, I just want to see: **Theorem 1.1, Theorem 1.2**, not **1, Theorem 1.1, Theorem 1.2**

Comment: But if there is no Section 1, what should be the meaning of `1.1` in theorem?

Comment: You can change the value of the `section` counter (even if you don't use `\section{})` by `\setcounter{section}{1}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I suppose you are using `article` document class.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{document}

No section here.

\begin{theorem}
hello
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
hello again 
\end{theorem}

\section{title}

\begin{theorem}
hello
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
hello again 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user_hello1, observe that next time you use `\section{}` the counter will be `2`.